# query posts returns 10 records

Tags: custom-taxonomy, query-posts, pagination, taxonomy, genesis-theme-framework

I am using the following code to fetch records from a custom taxonomy.

```
if ($_GET['post_type'] == "developments"){ ?>
                    <?php 
                    global $wp_query;
                    $paged = $wp_query->query_vars['paged'];

                    $development_args = array(
                        'post_type' => $_GET['post_type'],
                        'orderby' =>'title',
                        'order' => 'ASC',
                        'posts_per_page' => 14,
                        'paged' => $paged, 
                        's' => $_GET['search_building_name'],
                    );
                    $development_args['meta_query'] = array(
                        'relation'=>'AND',
                        array(
                            'key' => 'total_units',
                            'type' => 'numeric',
                            'value' => $_GET['search_total_units'],
                            'compare' => $_GET['total_units_operator']
                        ),
                        array(
                            'key' => 'total_floors',
                            'type' => 'numeric',
                            'value' => $_GET['search_total_floors'],
                            'compare' => $_GET['total_floors_operator']
                        ),
                    );
                    $development_args['tax_query'] = array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'type',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => $_GET['search_type'],
                            //'operator' => 'AND'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'amenities',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => $_GET['search_amenities'],
                            'operator' => 'AND'
                        ),
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'style',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => $_GET['search_style'],
                            'operator' => 'AND'
                        ),
                    );
                    if ($_GET['search_neighborhood'] != 'any'){
                    $development_args['tax_query'][] = array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'neighborhood',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => $_GET['search_neighborhood'],
                        );
                    }
                    if ($_GET['search_developer'] != 'any'){
                    $development_args['tax_query'][] = array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'developer',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => $_GET['search_developer'],
                        );
                    }                       
                    if ($_GET['search_architect'] != 'any'){
                    $development_args['tax_query'][] = array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'architect',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => $_GET['search_architect'],
                        );
                    }                       
                    if ($_GET['search_delivered'] != 'any'){
                    $development_args['tax_query'][] = array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'delivered',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => $_GET['search_delivered'],
                        );
                    }                       

                    query_posts($development_args );
                }
```

$wp_query->post_count returns 10, even when the actual number of records is lot more. I have tried various solutions but none work for me. This question could be a duplicate but i am asking this again because even a few answers have worked for other people but none have given a good explanation. 
Thanks

Comment: That is a lot of conditions. Are you sure there are more than 10? Tip: Don't use `query_posts` use a new `WP_Object` instead and `var_dump` the object afterwards. You can see the actual SQL. Maybe that will give you a clue as to the problem.

Comment: yes i am sure that it has more than 10

Comment: Then try the debugging suggestion. It may help you spot why the query is returning  the wrong count.

Answer (score -1):

Try taking out the `'paged' => $paged` parameter, as it is simply returning the amount of results for that page, which seems to be set at 10.

(You will need to do two separate queries - one for getting the true count, and one for displaying the posts in a paginated format.)

Comment: You don't need two queries, `$wp_query->found_posts` will give you the total number of posts for the query, regardless of pagination parameters. It looks like `posts_per_page` is set to 14 though, according to the query vars, so it would seem to not be related to pagination.

Comment: `$wp_query->found_posts` is much better! didn't know about this